# How to check if a particular user is logged in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-blade

How would I check if a particular user is logged in on one of my views? When a user logs in to their account, I want them to be able to see an update feature on their `show` page. I thought it would be something like this

```
@if (Auth::id == $player->user->id)
@yield ('update_content')
@endif
```

But I get an error for an undefined class constant of `id`. Any ideas on how to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@if (Auth::id() == $player->user->id)
    @yield ('update_content')
@endif
```

or

```
@if (Auth::user()->id == $player->user->id)
    @yield ('update_content')
@endif
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. Can this same logic work for routes?

Comment: routes you have to use middleware - https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
@if (Auth::check())
    @yield ('update_content')
@endif
```

or

```
  @guest

      // Logout

  @else

       @yield ('update_content')

  @endguest
```

Comment: I know this works to check if someone is logged in, but doesn't work only for a particular user. When I do this, every logged in user would see the update button on everyone's show page.